# When trying to export libgdx desktop using command on android studio, the command is not recognized

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, gradlew

So I went onto the internet to find out how to export my libgdx project from android studio, and I learned that you can generate it by using the command `gradlew desktop:dist`. But when I type this into the terminal window in android studio, it says, `'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the terminal can't find the gradlew program. If you're using Linux, make sure to type `./gradlew`- but my guess is that you're using windows.

First, use your file browser to navigate to your project directory and make sure that `gradlew.bat` is present. If it isn't, you don't have gradlew as part of your project and need to go get it from [The Gradle Website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

If you have `gradlew.bat`, make sure that your terminal is navigated to your project directory. On windows you can see where it is currently pointed using `echo %cd%` - if it doesn't show your current directory, you need to use the `cd` command to navigate to your project directory.

You can also confirm you're in the right place by running `dir` in the terminal- you should see `gradlew.bat`.